# display only youtube video sticky post

Tags: youtube

I want to display (on the home page) only the youtube video (or vimeo) of a sticky post.

I found this code from

```
/*Sticky list variables en page d'accueil*/
function wpb_latest_sticky() { 

/* Get all sticky posts */
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );

/* Get the 5 newest stickies (change 5 for a different number) */
$sticky = array_slice( $sticky, 0, 1 );

/* Query sticky posts */
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post__in' => $sticky, 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1 ) );
// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
$return .= '<ul>';
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();
$return .= '<li><a href="' .get_permalink(). '" title="'  . get_the_title() . '">'     . get_the_title() . '</a><br />' . get_the_content(). '</li>';



}
$return .= '</ul>';

} else {
// no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();

return $return; 

} 
add_shortcode('latest_stickies', 'wpb_latest_sticky');
```

I have so 2 issues:

- it will display all the content of the post.
- the youtube video is show as a link, wp not embed the video directly into the homepage.

Any help would be apreciate.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `get_the_content()` some filters aren't applied like they would with `the_content()` so if you want your content to be formatted you have to use the following:
`$my_content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() )`

If you want to extract the youtube video out of your content you'll have to detect the youtube link with a regex and then apply the filter on the extracted url.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content

Comment: Thank you Mathieu i will investigate further on this way